# Getting undefined on textarea

Tags: extjs

I am getting undefined on textareafield.. I have se the id to: `msgArea`, but extjs changes the id to: `msgArea-inputEl` on runtime. I have tried using both these ids, but getting undefined on both.

```
    isoNS.PanelQDisableInfoMsg = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
    title: 'Improtant information', 
    width: $(document).width() / 2,
    height: $(document).height() / 3,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    style: 'position: absolute; top: 100px;',
    id: 'infoWindow',
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #DFE9F6; background-image: none;',
            readOnly: true,
            height: ($(document).height() / 3) - 80,
            inputId: 'msgArea',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Ok',
            id: 'OkButton',
            docked: 'bottom',
            handler: function() {
                var win = Ext.getCmp("infoWindow");
                win.close();
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Test',
            handler: function() {
                var textArea = Ext.getCmp("msgArea");
                textArea.setValue("Text changed");
            }
        }
    ]   
}).show();
```

The code that gives the undefined is this part:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Test',
    handler: function() {
        var textArea = Ext.getCmp("msgArea-inputEl");
        textArea.setValue("Text changed");
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Also. How do I make extjs NOT to change the id on runtime from `msgArea` to: `msgArea-inputEl`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact version of your Extjs. The api on http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/ says:

```
inputId : String
```

> The id that will be given to the generated input DOM element. Defaults
>   to an automatically generated id. If you configure this manually, you
>   must make sure it is unique in the document.
>
> Available since: 4.0.0

If you uses an older version of Extjs, the api offers the object property `id:`. According these descriptions if you use this, the framework won't assign an automatic generated object id to this element.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I am using version 4.1.1

Comment: It solved the issue about changing the id dynamically. Thanks. I still have the issue with undefined though. For some reason, it can't find the textareaField with: inputId: 'msgArea'